# How to pass an struct (with no atributes, only methods) to a trigonometrical function?

Tags: class, templates, c++17

my problem is, I have an class that is supposed to be an X for a function, for example

```
auto f = x * x + 7.0;
```

and when called with f.e(3) it would return the function value.

It was resolved with operator overload on the * and +, but when i would try to do with trigonometrical functions, it doesnt work.

Here's what i've been trying to do:

```
auto f = sin(x);
```

that would later be invoked with an

```
f.e(5);
```

But its unable to do that because sin only accepts numbers as arguments, how would i go about doing that?

Here's class X:

```
class X {
  public:
  double e( double v ) {
    return v;
  }
};
```

The full code required to simply make it work is quite big, so I'm posting it on pastebin:

```
pastebin.com/SwKUUbyr
```

It also calculates the 1st derivative of the function.

This is the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sin(X&)'
```

I'd love any input you guys can provide.

Comment: You can't do this using the syntax you want in C++ without manually writing each function that can operate on `x`.  Your specific kind of overloading is ill-advised as well.  If you manually write each operation on `x`, this is plausible

Comment: It might be good to explain that you’re doing automatic differentiation, since that’s the justification for this complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>

namespace formula {
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
struct Times;
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
struct Plus;


template<class D>
struct Formula {
  double ex( double in ) { return static_cast<D&>(*this).ex(in); }
  double dx( double in ) { return static_cast<D&>(*this).dx(in); }

  template<class Rhs>
  friend auto operator*( Formula<D>, Formula<Rhs> ) {
    return Formula< Times<D, Rhs> >{};
  }
  template<class Rhs>
  friend auto operator+( Formula<D>, Formula<Rhs> ) {
    return Formula< Plus<D, Rhs> >{};
  }
};
struct X:Formula<X> {
  double ex(double in){ return in; }
  double dx(double in){ return 1; }
};
X x;

template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
struct Times:Formula<Times<Lhs, Rhs>> {
  double ex( double in ) {
    return Lhs{}.ex(in) * Rhs{}.ex(in);
  }
  double dx( double in ) {
    return Lhs{}.ex(in) * Rhs{}.dx(in) + Lhs{}.dx(in) * Rhs{}.ex(in);
  }
};
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
struct Plus:Formula<Plus<Lhs, Rhs>> {
  double ex( double in ) {
    return Lhs{}.ex(in) + Rhs{}.ex(in);
  }
  double dx( double in ) {
    return Lhs{}.dx(in) + Rhs{}.dx(in);
  }
};
```

That is a bit better machinery that replicates what yours does.

Now to extend it:

```
template<class X>
struct Sin:Formula<Sin<X>> {
  double ex( double in ) {
    return ::std::sin(X{}.ex(in));
  }
  double dx( double in ) {
    return X{}.dx(in) * ::std::cos(X{}.ex(in));
  }
};

template<class X>
auto sin( Formula<X> ) {
  return Sin<X>{};
}
}
```

Test code:

```
using namespace formula;
auto x_2 = x*x;
auto sin_x_2 = sin(x_2);
std::cout << sin_x_2.ex(0.) << "\n";
std::cout << sin_x_2.dx(0.) << "\n";
std::cout << sin(x).ex(0.) << "\n";
std::cout << sin(x).dx(0.) << "\n";
std::cout << (x*x).ex(1.) << "\n";
std::cout << (x*x).dx(1.) << "\n";
```

This can be extended with storing copies of the formula you depend upon to allow equations to contain some state.